# Microsoft Azure Detect Api how to pass image as data uri

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, axios, blob

My React application captures the webcam image in data uri format (e.g. data:image/jpeg;base64, iVBOR...). I then send the image in this form to my API in Node.js from where I use Axios to send it to the Microsoft Azure Detect API. However, I get an error

> error: {
> code: 'InvalidImage',
> message: 'Decoding error, image format unsupported.'
> }

My Node.js code:

```js
app.post('/detect', async (req, res) => {
    const dataUrl = req.body.imageDataUrl;
    if (dataUrl.length === 0) return;

    axios.post(
        url,
        {url: dataUrl},
        {
            timeout: 50000,
            headers: {
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            },
            params: {
                returnFaceId: false,
                returnFaceLandmarks: false,
                returnFaceAttributes: faceAttributes,
                detectionModel: detectionModel,
            },
        }
    );
});
```

I tried to convert a data uri to a blob using this function

```js
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var data = dataURI.split(',')[1];
    var byteString = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');

    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    var blob = new Blob([byteString], {type: mimeString});
    return blob;
};
```

but then the error message looks

> error: { code: 'InvalidImageSize', message: 'Image size is too small.' }

even though the size of the captured image is 1280x720

Answer (score 0):

- Here you are setting the content type to`application/octet-stream` but you are passing a string i.e., your URL so you  have to set it to `application/json`
- Then you can create a Json object which can passed which is of following format.

```
{
    "url":"<Your Image URL >"
}
```

- Here I tried have tried this in postman

Headers:
[image]

Params:
[image]
Body:
[image]

Output :
[image]

Refer this [MSDOC](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) on detect api.